# Iterate through dictionary and placing data in PyQt5 table

Tags: python, dictionary, pyqt5

I have a dictionary with the following structure.

```
 self.data = [{'username':'Homer', 'address':'11.11.111.111'}, {'username':'Bart', 'address':'22.22.222.222'}]
```

What I am trying to do is display this data in a table in PyQt5. What I have tried to do is something like the following:

```
    for rowIndex, username in enumerate(self.data["username"]["address"]):
        itemName = QTableWidgetItem(username["name"])  # fills cell with material name
        itemName.setFlags(QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled)  # makes cell read only
        itemAddress = QTableWidgetItem()  # creates widget for cell
        itemAddress.setData(username["address"])  # fills material amount and makes it editable

        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowIndex, 0, itemName)  # positioning cell
        self.tableWidget.setItem(rowIndex, 1, itemAddress)  # positioning cell
```

Doing this I get the following error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This is understandable because it is in a string format, How could I display the data like the following table?

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      username       |     address      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|     test user       |  11.111.111.111  |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Any Help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is `self.data` is a list, not a dictionary; therefore `self.data["username"]` is wrong. Here is a suggested fix:

```
    for rowIndex, record in enumerate(self.data):
        itemName = QTableWidgetItem(record['username'])
        itemAddress = QTableWidgetItem(record['address'])
        # more ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it helped tremendously!

Answer (score 1):

You have a list, not a dictionary. `[dict, dict, dict]` is a `list` of `dicts`. That means you can access it like this:

```
self.data[0] # Get the zeroth dict in list
```

Or iterate through it like this:

```
new_data = [x[key][sub_key] for x in self.data] # All must be dict-like in this list
```

Or any of the other things `list`s can do, but not `dict`s.

The error is:

```
enumerate(self.data["username"]["address"])
```

Specifically: `["username"]` when an `int` is expected for accessing a `list` with `[]`